# I am not able update UI after every call of sleep in android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, handler, sleep

My application is just like LUDO game. I am developing it in android. 
What i want is that after every roll dice my piece (player's playing piece) has to move in square boxes one by one means in one step the piece go in NEXT box and in next step it must go in the next box till the count of the Dice...

I have implemented so many strategies including thred, timertask, handler, etc..

But one common thing happen is that it just wait for what ever time we have passed for every step (means if player rolls dice and gets 4 then whatever time for one step for example say 0.5 sec multiply by 4 i.e. 2 seconds) and at the end of that time it updates the UI.
Here what I want is that i want to update UI after every time interval ( 0.5 sec as mentioned in previous bracket)till the final step or end of player's move one by one.

Help me with this as soon as possible...

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way round. _Android_ updates the UI for you as fast as it can/as it makes sense. But you are _sleep_ing on the main/UI thread, keeping Android from doing its work. You need to perform your game logic in short `Handler` runnables/message processing callbacks or have a concurrent `Thread` for that.

Comment: I can not get your answer exactly...Do you want me to use [handler] instead of thread to update UI....I have not much of programming experience in android so please explain me thoroughly...Thank you for your reply

Comment: Why don't you just work your way through the documentation/training? E.g. [Building Apps with Graphics & Animation](http://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html) although I'm getting the impression that you should start with the first lesson.

Comment: U r right...I haven't learned android for game development...but due to my deadline to submit project I have to make project in short time so I have chosen this approach....And thanks for the link to learn graphics and animation for android....

Comment: Don't let Android fool you. Compatibility with Android 2 (45% market share) and 4 (54% market share) as well as a wide variety of CPUs and GPUs (single core 600MHz to quad core 1.9GHz) won't make your life easy. Also, there are some points where you'd have to completely re-design your app if you don't address basic Android concepts correctly right from the beginning. I'd highly recommend to read the API Guide _first_. Of course, there are many people here who hope to get along with a bit of copy-pasted code. But I can't judge whether or not you can afford to not understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using canvas for your game it just not updating your UI in every Step might be  of 2 reason .
        1 you need to increment the position by the single pixel suppose one box is of 48
        pixel then just increment pixels 48+48+48+48 if you got 4....and 
        2. is call invalidate() in every increment of single pixel position.

I hope this might help you..:-)

Comment: Actually I am not using canvas for images...I am just using imageview to reference image or player's piece....so I am not able to implement your strategy in my game in current phase...thank you for your reply